# No source code on zombie stack trace from message to de-allocated instance of [CALayer]

Tags: ios, calayer, zombie-process

I am hoping someone can assist in how to trace a message to a de-allocated instance of [CALayer] when the stack trace does not link back to the source code.

I have enabled Zombie Objects in the Diagnostics of XCode and run it through the Zombie profiling.

The response in XCode is "2013-01-27 22:37:31.506 AdventureA[9695:11303] *** -[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x757b530"

The response from the instruments is:
[image: Instruments - Zombie]

I am totally at a loss as to how to find out what is causing the issue; I have been looking through the source code for hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - found it.  There was a UIButton (which, of course, inherits from UIView) that was being instantiated as a buttonWithType and for I was releasing it.  D'oh.

The reasons something so obvious became such a pain (for those who may have to deal with the same thing); the problem is that is all sounds so easy in hindsight:

- I still have no idea why there is no stack trace that allowed me to
  be able to track where the issue was happening.
- With no source code being available from the Zombie output I was
  directed to thinking this was something happening "under the covers"
- I was looking at the View in place at the time the error was
  happening when I should have been looking at the previous view which
  was being affected by the de-allocation.
- I had been coding since this morning...

Answer (score 0):

Note the two calls to [UIView dealloc] in the caller list.  Look at the allocations for UIView objects.  You seem to have one with a strange lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the response; got me back to looking again.  Did the sensible thing and did something else for a while...